# Compiler error while declaring an array: compiler is unable to type-check ... distinct sub-expressions

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using healthkit and getting the permision to read data. When asking for 5 data types it is fine. Although, when one more is added it gives me the error `The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions`. 
**Here is the Code**

```
let healthkitTypesToRead = NSSet(array: [
            HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.height) ?? "",
            HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMass) ?? "",
            HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate) ?? "",
            HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.sleepAnalysis) ?? "",
            HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodPressureDiastolic) ?? "",
            HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodPressureSystolic) ?? ""



            ]
        )
```

Comment: I think a big part of the issue is that you are trying to create an array containing values of type `HKQuantityType` and `String`.

Comment: I need to include the strings because it is an expected expression after operator.

Comment: But why do you want strings if the `HKQuantityType` is `nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you've injected `?? ""` into this code. That appears to be meaningless (it says "if I can't add this quantityType, then add a string, which makes no sense). I think what you mean is "I just want these to be added if they're non-nil, and really they should be, but I don't want to add `!` and crash if I'm wrong." If that's what you mean, then this is what you mean:

```
let healthkitTypesToRead = Set<HKObjectType>([
    .quantityType(forIdentifier: .height),
    .quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMass),
    .quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate),
    .categoryType(forIdentifier: .sleepAnalysis),
    .quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressureDiastolic),
    .quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressureSystolic),
    ].compactMap { $0 }
)
```

However, these are all compile-time constants. If any of them fail, that's really a programming mistake. That is a point where `!` is appropriate, and so I would personally write it this way (but this is just a matter of opinion and style):

```
let healthkitTypesToRead = Set<HKObjectType>([
    .quantityType(forIdentifier: .height)!,
    .quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMass)!,
    .quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!,
    .categoryType(forIdentifier: .sleepAnalysis)!,
    .quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressureDiastolic)!,
    .quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressureSystolic)!,
    ]
)
```

Note I've replaced `NSSet` with `Set`. Unless you have a very strong reason, you should not use `NSSet` here.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
   protocol HKCustomContainer: Hashable { }
extension HKCategoryTypeIdentifier: HKCustomContainer { }
extension HKQuantityTypeIdentifier: HKCustomContainer { }
let identifierArray: [HKCustomContainer] = [
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.height,
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMass,
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate,
    HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.sleepAnalysis,
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodPressureDiastolic,
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodPressureSystolic
]

let hkObjectTypeArray: [String] = identifierArray.compactMap {
    if let qt = $0 as? HKQuantityTypeIdentifier {
        return HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: qt) ?? ""
    } else if let ct = $0 as? HKCategoryTypeIdentifier {
        return HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: ct) ?? ""
    }
    return nil
}
print(Set(hkObjectTypeArray))
```

Comment: This still suffers from the problem that the resulting array is a mix of two different types.

Comment: SleepAnalysis is type HKCategoryTypeIdentifier. How would I do that?

Comment: @rmaddy they have got the same root class: `HKSampleType`

Comment: It is mixing 3 different types.

Comment: @JacobKantor so provide the full list of items and types

Comment: @JacobKantor regarding https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkcategorytypeidentifier has the same struct types

Comment: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier, HKCategoryTypeIdentifier(sleep analysis), and Strings.

Comment: @JacobKantor you can use protocol

Comment: I used the second method although I get this error Type 'HKCustomContainer' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'. I declared protocol HKCustomContainer { } .

Comment: @Vyacheslav How do I properly declare it?

Comment: protocol HkCustomContainer: Hashable { }

Comment: I redeclared using the new way and now it gives me this error Using 'HKCustomContainer' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'Hashable' is not supported

Comment: @JacobKantor I've tested in the playground. This code should work. I've updated it.

Comment: I still have errors. Such as : Protocol 'HKCustomContainer' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements ; Cannot convert value of type 'HKQuantityType?' to expected argument type 'String?'  ; Cannot convert value of type 'HKCategoryType?' to expected argument type 'String?'